# Why the pattern for microservices distributed transactions named as SAGA?

Tags: java, design-patterns, microservices, distributed-transactions, saga

I have gone through various **SAGA patterns**(*Orchestration,Choreography*), suggested for maintaining database consistency in microservices during distributed transactions.

But I am not able to relate the literal word **SAGA** in the context.

*Why is it named as **SAGA*** ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about programming.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Saga is not an abbreviation. The term “saga” was first defined in a 1987 [publication](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/cs711/2002fa/reading/sagas.pdf). It also mentions that it was proposed by Bruce Lindsay.

In their original version, the term saga refers to Long Lived Transactions(LLT).

> A LLT is a saga if it can be written as a sequence of transactions that can be interleaved
> with other transactions.

The reason for choosing the word itself is not disclosed.
Perhaps one of the [literary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/saga) meanings of the word saga was meant:

> a long, detailed story of connected events

Answer (score 7):

The term saga refers to Long Lived Transactions (LLT). Let's assume it as abbreviation (which is not preferable in some way). So, in terms of microservices, you can think of **S**egregated **A**ccess of **G**lobal **A**tomicity

Comment: Long live SAGA!